# Weil divisors on non Noetherian schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, examples, divisors

Let X be an integral scheme that is separated (say over an affine scheme). Define a Weil divisor as a finite integral combination of height 1 points of X, where the height of a point of X is the dimension of its local ring.  Let Z be a closed subscheme of X, Z not equal to X.

Is there an example of such an X and Z where Z contains infinitely many Weil divisors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are such examples (with *X* quasi-compact, otherwise it is trivial). There is a general result due to Hochster ("Prime Ideal structures in commutative rings", his thesis) which says that spectra of rings are exactly those topological spaces *X* such that:

1) *X* is Kolmogorov (*T*_0).

2) *X* is quasi-compact.

3) The quasi-compact open subsets form an open basis.

4) *X* is quasi-separated, i.e., quasi-compact open subsets are closed under finite intersections.

5) Every non-empty irreducible closed subset has a generic point.

We will construct an irreducible topological space *X* satisfying 1-5 with underlying set 2^**N** U {*x*} such that 2^**N** is closed in *X* and totally disconnected and *X* has generic point *x*. If *X*=Spec(*A*), then the closed subvariety 2^**N** is a union of infinitely many Weil divisors. (*X* has dimension 1)

The topology on 2^**N** will be the product topology, i.e., that of the 2-adic integers (or if you prefer, the Cantor set). An open basis for this topology are cylinders, i.e., sets where a finite number of components are fixed. The cylinders are also closed. The space 2^**N** is Hausdorff, compact and totally disconnected, hence satisfies 1-5.

An open basis for the topology of *X* = 2^**N** U {*x*} is given by sets of the form *W* U {*x*} where *W* is a cylinder or the empty set. The quasi-compact open subsets of *X* are the finite unions of such sets and *X* satisfies 1-4. To see 2-4 note that if *V* is an open subset of *X* then

*V* is quasi-compact <=> The intersection of *V* and 2^**N** is clopen

Finally, the non-empty irreducible closed subsets of *X* are the singleton sets of 2^**N** and *X* itself and these all admit generic points so *X* satisfies 5.

**Remark**: *X* seems to be closely related to the spectrum of the Tate-algebra **Q**_p<*x*>. The *canonical* topology on the closed points are exactly the *p*-adic integers. But the *Zariski* topology is completely different (**Q**_p<*x*> is noetherian and regular of dimension 1).

Answer (score 3):

Let R be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Then $\dim (R)=1$ and there are infinitely many prime ideals lying above a prime ideal
$p\mathbb{Z}$. Hence the closed set $V(pR)$ has the required property.

Answer (score 0):

Take X to be A^\infty and Z to be the union of the coordinate hyperplanes.

**Edit:** Jonathan pointed out to me that the infinite union of hyperplanes in A^\infty is not a closed subscheme: any closed subscheme is contained in the pre-image of a closed subscheme from A^n for some n. So I withdraw my example.